# Parametrization of line segment on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces, curves, arc-length

So I have a regular surface  $S$ parametrized by $x(u,v)=(u,v,\sqrt(u^2 + v^2 +1))$ for $x,y\in R^2$ and I would like to find the arc length of the segment connecting two points $A=(0,0,1)$ and $B=(0,a,\sqrt(a^2 +1))$. From what I understand I can do this  using the first fundamental form and a parametrization of the line segment of the form $a(t)=x(u(t),v(t))$. I have calculated the coefficients of the fundamental form and have a parametrization of the segment $\gamma (t)=(1-t)*A+t*B$ but am not sure how I should go about finding the parametrization in the required form. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I notice that your formula for $a(t)$ defines a segment that lies in the surface, but your formula for $\gamma(t)$ does not do that. Which do you actually want to know the arc length of?

Comment: For that matter, the formula for $\gamma(t)$ seems odd... What's that $t$ doing after the $B$? Do those $*$ characters stand for scalar multiplication?

Comment: @LeeMosher My bad about the function, the * does stand for scalar multiplication and I removed the stray t. Yeah I would like the formula for the segment that lies on the surface, connecting the two points but am not sure how I should find $u(t),v(t)$.

Comment: So as it is defined in your post, $\gamma(t)$ definitely does not lie on the surface. So you would do best to forget about $\gamma(t)$ and stick with $a(t)$. Also, you write "the" segment, but there are many continuous paths from $A$ to $B$ that lie on the surface. Use the parameterization $x(u,v)$ to define them. Start with any old path in the $u,v$ plane, $(u(t),v(t))$ for $0 \le t \le 1$, such that $(u(0),v(0))=(0,0)$ and $(u(1),v(1))=(0,a)$. For example, $(u(t),v(t)) = (0,at)$, but there are many others. Then take $a(t)=x(u(t),v(t))$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks, was able to get the result I was expecting for the arc length!